# Assign IF statement to Form control combobox

Tags: excel, forms, vba, combobox

I have a form control combobox (named DropDown1) on a worksheet. I'm trying to assign an if statement but have been unable to do so.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    If DropDown1.Value = "test" Then
        Print (1)
    Else
        Print (2)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean ActiveX combobox?

Comment: form control combo box

Comment: I'm getting a object required error

Comment: Form controls do NOT have event procedures like `DropDown1_Change()`. Only ActiveX controls have those.

Comment: OK, thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the IF statement itself. What is wrong is what you are doing after the branching occurs.

In other words, the is no Print command. You can use Debug.Print, or you can use MsgBox.

Here is how the code should read:

```
Private Sub DropDown1_Change()
    If DropDown1.Value = "test" Then
        Debug.Print 1
    Else
        Debug.Print 2
    End If
End Sub
```